# Name of a movie: people trained to master elements, trainer changes sides

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

There was a movie I briefly remember watching sometime between 2000 and 2007 latest I think.

In it I remember there being this man who was originally on the dark side and in the beginning I think we saw him kill a woman. Moving forward he takes on a couple of people to train them in what I remember to be a dinghy dark looking place that I think may have been underground but I don't know. He was teaching them to master the elements. Each person had control over one element. One fire or light (I can't remember which), one wind, one water and one was iron or something along those lines.

He was training them to fight the bad guys (the dark side) who he once worked for but we didn't find out till near the end of their training. I vaguely remember him basically telling them that it was time to fight the bad guys and that they were one short (so a missing element power) (the woman we saw him kill in the beginning) but they had no choice but to go on without her.

The group were asking where this other person was which is why he then basically explained to them that he was once one of the bad guys and he was assigned to kill her and that's why she wasn't there. Nearer to the end of the film the group and their trainer/leader went to what I seem to remember being a fairly dark rooftop type place where they were fighting the bad guys and ended up winning.

I realise this isn't much to go on but any help in locating the film would be amazing. If it helps I seem to remember the trainer/leader guy was bald. I could be wrong but I don't think I am. Many thanks for any help in advance.

PS. I could have been wrong about us seeing him kill the woman at the beginning and instead it would have been shown when he was explaining to his group what he did, although I do think it was it he beginning. Once again many thanks for any help on finding this movie :-)

Comment: "If it helps I seem to remember the trainer/leader guy was bold." Do you mean *bald*?

Comment: Sounds like a Mortal Kombat movie to me. But it has been a very long time since I watched it.

Comment: Sounds like a prequel to that Avatar movie. There weren't any.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a lot like [Invincible](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216487/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) from 2001.
time fits, dark vs light fits, a bald guy in the movie fits also.

> The Shadow Men are immortal beings of darkness and destruction. One such Shadow Man, Os (Zane), is confronted by the White Warrior, a being of light, and given the chance to change his ways or die. After the White Warrior bests Os in combat, she opens his heart to the power of love, and charges him to find the warriors who are the representation of the five elements and will save the world from the threat of the Shadow Men and their leader, Slate.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not *[Warriors Of Virtue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warriors_of_Virtue)* ([IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120479/))?
Sounds VERY similar, especially the part about the one having control over Iron

> Ryan wakes in a strange forest and is attacked by assailants who are drawn off by a creature from the lake. He screams and runs in fear, but soon realizes his leg works. He meets a dwarven man named Mudlap, who leads him to a beautiful girl named Elysia who tells him that he is in Tao; Ryan tells her about the manuscript, which had been stolen with his backpack. Believing it to be the Manuscript of Legend, Elysia takes Ryan to Master Chung and he meets four of the five warriors; anthropomorphic kangaroos each representing an element: Lai; Warrior of wood, Chi; Warrior of Fire, Tsun; Warrior of Earth; and Yee, the Warrior of Metal. He is told that Yun; the Warrior of Water had left them following an earlier conflict and Ryan thinks that the creature that saved him is Yun and he has the manuscript. He is told that the manuscript would be sought by Komodo; a man who betrayed the Warriors and is stealing from the Lifesprings of Tao in order to stay young forever, and that they are protecting the last spring. While talking to Elysia, Ryan is captured by Mantose, Barbarocious and Dullard but is saved by Yun who admits he doesn't have the book, leading Ryan to believe Komodo has it and he convinces Yun to return to the Lifespring.
>
> Ryan flees, wanting to return home, but Mudlap leads him into Grillo's arms and he is saved by Chung. Yun, Yee and Chi go after the manuscript and fall into a trap after being betrayed by Elysia, who joined Komodo as vengeance against Yun for killing her brother by accident.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you add a synopsis of this film, e.g. by copying from the link? Link-only answers are discouraged here, since the link might die and render the answer almost useless.

Comment: Time doesnt fit, and reading the synopsis none of it fits either. Having said that I havent seen that movie so I dont know.

Comment: Ah sorry, long time lurker, never posted this side before.

It doesn't fit close enough reading it objectively, I agree. It just reminded me of this, regarding the similarities and I figured I'd put the suggestion out there